# Is there any way to have monit not try to restart a process?

Tags: monit

I have monit watching a process and killing it if it's running for too long. I do not want this process to be automatically restarted, however. I don't have a `start program` specified, but each cycle, monit logs that it can't restart the process. Is there any way to tell monit not to try to restart the process and/or suppress it from the log?

```
check process libreoffice matching soffice.bin
  if uptime > 2 then exec "/usr/bin/killall --older-than 2m soffice.bin"
```

Comment: Setup a rule to 'unmonitor' the service after whatever it is doing is complete?

Comment: That won't quite work - the process in question is for background processing so spins up on a unregular schedule, and I need to have monit watch it in case a process gets carried away.

Comment: Please show your monit config or the relevant stanza.

Comment: @ewwhite I updated my post with it.